# Change element property based on bound value

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to change properties on an Image element based on values in the bound object.

I have an image element:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Thing.Url}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

If `Thing.OtherProperty = true`, then I want to add `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to the Image element.

Note, the Image element is in a DataTemplate which is used in various places in the app.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you would use a [Binding Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter.aspx)

In your case you want to change the `HorizontalAlignment` property based on a Boolean.
You first need to write a class that implements `IValueConverter` where you will write your conversion logic:

```
public class AlignmentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        return Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*you will probably need to handle the errors a bit better in case you ever bind this to a property that is not boolean

To use this you need to import your coverters namespace at the top of the page

```
xmlns:converters="using:*yournamespace*"
```

...declare the converter as a resource:

```
<converters:AlignmentConverter x:Key="HorizontalAlignmentConverter"/>
```

... and use it as a parameter in your binding

```
<Image Source="{Binding Thing.Url}" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Thing.OtherProperty, Converter={StaticResource HorizontalAlignmentConverter}"/>
```